# Apply formulas across infinite columns, ARRAYFORMULA not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google form set up to track different expenses.

[image]

The first four columns are auto-filled, the last column is generated using,

`=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,C2,IF(D2 = "","",": "),D2)`

This works fine, but I have to apply it to the rows I want. In theory, if the form inputed thousands of rows, that would mean scrolling down and dragging the formula across all those rows.

The other method I have tried is `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE,C2:C,IF(D2:D = "","",": "),D2:D))`, however this ouputs all the text in one cell:

[image]

Are there any other solutions that will allow me to appended the two strings for each column, indefinatly across many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use simple concatenation rather than textjoin, either using concat or (as below) ampersand:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="","",if(D2:D="",C2:C,C2:C&" : "&D2:D)))
```

[image]